# \b behaving weird in IntelliJ's console

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sleep

I was trying to display a String and then clear it after some time.
The following code is working.

```
    String hello = "Hello";
    System.out.print(hello);
    int length = hello.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        System.out.print("\b");
```

But when I thought to display it for few seconds (Using `Thread.sleep(time)` ), it is not working (code below).
When I was debugging it I noticed that after the first execution of the loop, cursor starts pointing to the next line.

So, Is there any way to display for few seconds and then clear it.

```
String hello = "Hello";
System.out.print(hello);
int length = hello.length();
Thread.sleep(10);
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    System.out.print("\b");
```

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: Using Intellij Idea (ultimate) Terminal

Comment: on what operating system?

Comment: @MadPhysicist , windows (10)

Comment: IntelliJ does not support \b

Comment: @Meo , It works if I am not using Thread.sleep

Comment: probably only because it was flushed in one chunk, on which you can't rely.

Comment: This does that, but it is really low level, once that chunk gets printed to the console component, there is no way back, it only appends text https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/daaa6e228ec0418b034db88deee8c8e570c9d46b/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/execution/process/AnsiEscapeDecoder.java#L56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[<s>IDEA-86669</s> Console: support ASCII backspace symbol in console view](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-86669)

Comment: I do not know who down voted your comment and my question. But I found that this issue is already opened in the link you provided and its unresolved

Comment: I can not upvote it, because my reputation fell down from 16 to 11 because of downvote :/ , sorry

Comment: Regarding the answer, it is not an actual answer. Because answer is really donot use Intellij or eclipse (because it worked in netbeans and command line)

Comment: You asked about IntelliJ, this is the best answer you will get. Maybe it will be implemented in the future.

Comment: you are right (I also updated the tag to intellij). And, In that context, I am accepting this answer